# Include a Spring boot module in exisiting project

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to include only one spring boot module in my mutli module project. 
That is my project layout : 
`-module parent
   -module-service
   -module-web
   -module-dao (Using Spring BOOT)
     .com.test.dao.Application.java
...`

The class Application.java ;

```
    @SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The pom.xml of module dao :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.40</version>
        </dependency>           
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I have well configured mysql properties in the application.properties.

My question is : Is it possible to include a spring boot module in an existing mutli module project that not use Sring boot?

Thanks

Comment: yes you can do it, declare in module-dao pom

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can include a module using spring-boot into an existing multi module project.

Maven does not care about the frameworks and libraries you use, so building may be no problem.

You may obtain some version conflicts, if the other modules use older spring versions.
Than you need to update all spring versions to those, used by the spring-boot module.

In your app you need to configure a spring context with beans of all modules, using for example @Import or @ComponentScan.